# swagger jersey REST API doesn't work

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I followed the step to add Swagger to my already built Jersey REST API project in TOMCAT

1. Added:

> ```
> swagger-annotations-1.3.10.jar
> swagger-core_2.10-1.3.10.jar
> swagger-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.10.jar
> swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.10.jar
> ```

2. Added in web.xml

   contextClass
           
               org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
           
       
       
           contextConfigLocation
           com.estartup.config.PersistenceConfig

   ```
   <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>


   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>com.estartup.config.Application</param-value>
       </init-param>

       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>api.version</param-name>
           <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
           <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```

Application class:

```
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public Application(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        register(new ServiceBinder());
        register(com.estartup.feature.JacksonFeature.class);            
        packages(true, "com.estartup", "com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json","com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing");

    }

}
```

However, when I navigate to

`http://localhost:8080/api/api-docs` I get `HTTP Status 404 - page not found.`

:(. In the logs I do see that swagger is being loaded like this:
What is wrong?

```
15935 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.WebXMLReader - set api.version to 1.0.0
15935 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.WebXMLReader - set swagger.api.basepath to http://localhost:8080/api
```

Comment: Is this being deployed with Jetty or another application server?

Comment: Thanks I am using tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, if your application is deployed on Tomcat, than that's most likely the wrong URL.

Say the context root of your application is `myapp`, then your API itself will be deployed available on `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/...` and the same way, the swagger docs would be available on `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/api-docs`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this configuration:

`pom.xml`:

```xml
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

`web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>your.package.name.YourApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>your.package.name.SwaggerApplication</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

`SwaggerApplication.java`:

```java
public class SwaggerApplication extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6039834823506457822L;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();

        final String contextPath = config.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        final StringBuilder sbBasePath = new StringBuilder(); 
        sbBasePath.append(contextPath);
        sbBasePath.append("/rs");
        beanConfig.setBasePath(sbBasePath.toString());

        // API Info
        beanConfig.setVersion("0.1");
        beanConfig.setTitle("My Swagger APP");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("your.package.name");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

To access your Swagger JSON: `http://<your-app>/<your-context>/rs/swagger.json`